# Variable scope in C# - use session or class?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner with C# and I'm having a problem with variable scope. So ... here's my code in hopes that someone can help me find a way to make my variable "s" be accessible in both my switch/case and then near the bottom with the "SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, conn);" statement. If that isn't possible, I'd like a recommendation on how to restructure this code and/or what to add to get the "s" I come up with in the switch/case statement - get that value down to the SqlCommand statement. 
Should I use a session variable or class? If so, how/where?
Oh and would you say I don't need this: "using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))"
Thanks!

Here's the code in my ASPX page:

```js
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

   
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs ec)
{
    //level 01   
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Database=db; User Id=user; password=pw"))
    {
        //level 02
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //level 03
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            string s;
            string u = Request.QueryString["u"];
            if (u == "specificstring")
            {
                //level 04
                string sCmd = Request.QueryString["sCmd"];
                string IDCategory;
                string sCategory;
                string sDefaultEventSort;
                //string s;
                switch (sCmd)
                {
                    case "GetCategoryNames":
                        s = "SELECT";
                        //s += " Id";
                        s += " name";
                        //s += ", defaultSort";
                        s += " FROM Category";
                        s += " WHERE";
                        s += " (";
                        s += " ShowOnHomePage=1";
                        s += " AND IncludeInTopMenu=1";
                        s += " AND Published=1";
                        s += " )";
                        s += " ORDER BY name";
                        //s = "SELECT name FROM Category ORDER BY name";
                        break;
                    case "GetCategoryId":
                        sCategory = Request.QueryString["sCategory"];
                        s = "SELECT";
                        s += " Id";
                        s += " FROM Category";
                        s += " WHERE";
                        s += " (";
                        s += " [name]='" + sCategory + "'";
                        s += " )";
                        break;
                }

                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>(rdr.FieldCount);
                        for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            d[rdr.GetName(i)] = rdr.GetValue(i);
                        }
                        list.Add(d);
                    }
                    JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    Response.Write(j.Serialize(list.ToArray()));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                    Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    Response.Write("Error occurred. Query=" + s + "\n");
                    Response.Write(e.ToString());
                }
                //level 04
            }
            Response.End();
            //level 03
        }
        //level 02
    }
    //level 01
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like it should be as simple as `string s=null;` rather than `string s;` (presumably the error you're seeing is because the variable is not defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `s` first as your switch statement does not guarantee to initialize `s`;

```
string s = string.empty;
```

or

```
string s = null;
```

Or you could add a default case to your switch statement to ensure `s` is initialized:

```
default:
    s = string.Empty; //or some default sql query
    break;
```

A better structure would be the following:

Take the `try/catch` out of the second level `using` statement and instead wrap both `using` statements in the `try/catch` block, in other words make your `try/catch` the parent level. It is not wrong, where the `try/catch` block is now, it is just that you are not using it specifically to capture `SqlCommand` exceptions per se, your catching any `Exception` and returning its error message in your HTTP response. So make the `try/catch` the most outter level block wrapping your using statements.

```
try
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //use sb to build the SQL string query

   using (SqlConnection conn = CreateSqlConnection(connString))
    {
       using (SqlCommand command = CreateSqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn)
       {
           //open connection + execute command 
       }
    }

{
catch(Exception ex) 
{
}
```

Why use StringBuilder instead of concatenating a string variable?
Because C# string is immutable, meaning that every time you concatenated to the string, C# must create a copy of the string. StringBuilder is a fast, mutable string object that will build your sql string faster.

You do not need `StreamReader`, you are not even using `sr` anywhere and wrapping up your code in a `StreamReader` `using` statement does nothing for the code inside that `using` statement.

Please take note of @LukeBriggs mentions of security issues in his answer, if you use Stored Procedures to pass arguments or Entity Framework you can mitigate Sql Injection attacks, I would say though, since you are just learning, the security aspect might be a bit overwhelming, and you have no security issues to worry about until actually build something people will use, your software has to be "on the radar" to worry about security vulnerabilities is a way you can look at it for now so you can keep learning without getting overwhelmed.

Comment: s is declared a level higher than the try/catch block anyway so this won't work - It's likely that the error he's actually seeing is 'use of unassigned local variable' which is making him doubt his scoping.

Comment: ..As you're now copying my answer, you should also copy the security notice too :P

Comment: @LukeBriggs oh nice on the security notice! no I don't want to copy your answer, he has good information on both, I was double checking the try/catch use of unassigned local variable in a console application, you are correct of course :)

Answer (score 2):

**Security notice:** On secondary checking, your code is also **vulnerable to database injections**. You must either [escape your values or use prepared queries](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html).

Your concept of scoping appears to be correct; presumably the error you're actually seeing looks like this:

> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 's'

This is because you've got code flows which use `s` where no value has been set to it. Compare this:

```
string s; // No value declared just yet; only the type

if(u == "specificstring"){
   s="Something";
}
```

What's s supposed to be when u is *not* `specificstring`? It's not defined. This is what triggers the above error - in your case, it's specifically when `sCmd` is neither of the options in your switch. You might know that it can't be anything else, but the compiler doesn't. Compare it to this:

```
string s=null; // A null value has been defined no matter what

if(u == "specificstring"){
   s="Something";
}
```

In this case, s is `null` when u is not `specificstring`, which is fine. Similarly this works too:

```
string s; // A null value has been defined no matter what

if(u == "specificstring"){
    s="Something";
}else{
    s=null;
}
```

But your code has multiple cases where s could be undefined, so setting it to null (or some other value for those unspecified cases) would be easier.